# GeoCoder is returning one of value as null

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I am trying to get details of Country,State,City,Pincode,SubRegion,Address.But sometimes it returns City as null or SubRegion as null.Heres the image attached[image]

Here's my code..

```
 String locationCountry = "", locationState = "", locationCity = "", locationPincode = "", locationSubRegion = "", locationAddress = "";
    Geocoder gCoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;


    GPStracker g = new GPStracker(getApplicationContext());
            Location l = g.getLocation();


            if (l != null) {
                latitude = l.getLatitude();
                longitude = l.getLongitude();

            }else {
                 l = g.getLocation();
            }

            gCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                addresses = gCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {

                    locationCountry = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    locationState = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                    locationCity = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    locationPincode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                    locationSubRegion = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
                    locationAddress = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

Comment: the result is same for different lat longs?

Comment: The code is written in onCreate() method. No some times  I get Locality and subLocality is null. But some or other of these two is null.

Comment: This API will return the values depending on lat long, if the API database doesn't have these values then it will return NULL only, in my knowledge there's nothing you can do about it. You have to handle these cases gracefully so your app don't crash.

Comment: ok like can you explain how can I handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geo coder API will return the values depending on lat long, if the API database doesn't have these values(city then it will return NULL only, in my knowledge there's nothing you can do about it. You have to handle these cases gracefully so your app don't crash.

Handling these cases includes you have to put a check using `if` condition is that particular value is null or it has some value, because if you use any of the value somewhere in code without checking and if that value is Null then app might crash whenever that particular value comes null.